# Cross-validated average: metrics mean or ensembling probabilities?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

Let's say I have 5 models cross-validated via leave-one-out strategy. I have the predictions and scores of each model.

Now, it's time to calculate the average for the set of 5 models - am I supposed to:

- add up the 5 losses and divide them by 5?
- Or average their probabilities for each prediction and use the average probability to calculate new metrics like an ensemble/ forest?

Comment: are you actually interested in getting an average performance value for your five models? Or, as usually, you are interested in selecting the best model to be used afterwards?

Comment: @GermanCM I'm writing a library, so I want to provide whatever functionality is most generally useful. So if people are just picking the best model and moving on, it feels like the average doesn't much matter?

Answer (score 1):

A standard way to provide the performance of each model would be:

- providing, for each split, the value of the chosen metric (accuracy, roc_auc, etc) on the train and test sets (on your case, your one-out sample), something like this (in this case with 2 models):
  [image]
- as a final model performance (for each one of the 5 models), a mean metric value together with its standard deviation for the test sets is a way to inform about the model quality and its robustness, something like (preferably for the test set):

[image]

You have more detail on how to automatically get this done via [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.model_selection), and in [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/86912/k-fold-cross-validation-with-validation-and-test-set/86913#86913) and [this one](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/84971/compare-cross-validation-and-test-set-results/84973#84973).

By the way, consider using another strategy as stratified k-fold, in case you have a lot of samples, as leave-one-out would be very costly.

Comment: Okay for each model you want split stats, I get that. But wouldn't you want to know the average across all of those individual models?

Comment: Depending on your goal, do you want eventually to select the best model out of those 5 ones? Then, the answer is that you do not need the average across the 5 models; otherwise, do you want to build a final ensemble model?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple popular ways to ensemble models. Averaging, majority voting, selecting the one with the highest probability, learn a new model based on these 5 numbers are amongst the many methods available. Check also the Bayes optimal classifier which 'averages' these probabilities in a Bayes way:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning#Bayes_optimal_classifier